# Error when converting a pandas column price to integer

Tags: pandas

I got this error when trying to convert pandas column price to integer. I've attached the code problem
Can you help please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQGre.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because the price column isn't of string type to begin with

Comment: Thanks for replay, how to fix this error? Would you please give more details? thank you!

Comment: can you show `car_sales.dtypes`? it's probably already integer

Comment: As it shown, the price's type is float.

Comment: then you don't need `.str.replace`, just `.astype(int)`

Comment: Would you please update the code after removing.str.replace?

Answer (score 0):

change the type of a dataframe column using "astype" method.

`car_sales['Price'].astype(int)`

in general:

`df['column_name'].astype(type)`